# How to get the current active DB in Drupal 6?

Tags: database

You can easily print out the current db_name, by printing out $db_url. But there is no clear way in the API that allows you to print out the "key" for the active db. So I have two dbs, namely "testing" and "default". What php code can I run to find out whether I am currently using the "testing" db, or the "default" db?

I'm bascially looking for the inverse of "db_set_active". So If I do this:

```
db_set_active("default");
```

What can I call directly after it to find out which is the current active db (i.e. "default")?

Comment: I don't think you can, weirdly enough - any reference to the connection key is held statically inside `db_set_active()`, it isn't set globally anywhere

Comment: That's really silly of drupal. Not only can you not run stored procs natively, but now you can't even find out which db ur connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like drupal allows it inherently, so I'm posting my hack in the meantime. I'm open to any suggestions on improving this:

```
global $db_url;
$activeDBName = db_result(db_query('select database()'));
$mode = '';
foreach ($db_url as $key => $url) {
    if(strpos($url, $activeDBName) !== FALSE) {
        $mode = $key;
    }
}
```

$mode will then be whatever the active db is.

Comment: I think the only other solution would be to patch `db_set_active` and keep track of a global `$current_active_db` var